# MSBuild dúvida sobre compilação C#

Tags: c#, compilação, msbuild

Olá, estou com um projeto em C# windows forms e preciso compilar e gerar o `.exe` com o MSBuild. Porém, quando atualizo as fontes e executo para compilar, dá erro dizendo que a estrutura do código está errada: com ponto e virgula faltando, etc. 
Mas, se eu entrar no mesmo projeto, compilar pela IDE Visual Studio e depois ir fazer pelo MSBuild, funciona sem erros. No meu caso preciso fazer a compilação onde não tem a IDE instalada.

Muito obrigado.

Mensagem de erro na compilação com MSBUILD :

```
"D:\CRIS\Programas_Cris\Projeto\Projeto.sln" (destino padrão) (1) ->"D:\CRIS\Programas_Cris\Projeto\Projeto\Projeto.csproj" (destino padrão) (2) ->
  (CoreCompile destino) ->  FrmPrincipal.cs(117,54): error CS1525: Termo de expressão inválido 'int' [D:\CRIS\Programas_Cris\Projeto\Projeto\Projeto.csproj]
 FrmPrincipal.cs(117,65): error CS1002: ; esperado [D:\CRIS\Programas_Cris\Projeto\Projeto\Projeto.csproj]
  FrmPrincipal.cs(117,65): error CS1525: Termo de expressão inválido ',' [D:\CRIS\Programas_Cris\Projeto\Projeto\Projeto.csproj]
  FrmPrincipal.cs(117,67): error CS1002: ; esperado [D:\CRIS\Programas_Cris\Projeto\Projeto\Projeto.csproj]
  FrmPrincipal.cs(117,68): error CS1002: ; esperado [D:\CRIS\Programas_Cris\Projeto\Projeto\Projeto.csproj]
  FrmPrincipal.cs(117,68): error CS1525: Termo de expressão inválido ')' [D:\CRIS\Programas_Cris\Projeto\Projeto\Projeto.csproj]
  FrmPrincipal.cs(2028,55): error CS1525: Termo de expressão inválido 'int' [D:\CRIS\Programas_Cris\Projeto\Projeto\Projeto.csproj]
  FrmPrincipal.cs(2028,61): error CS1002: ; esperado [D:\CRIS\Programas_Cris\Projeto\Projeto\Projeto.csproj]
  FrmPrincipal.cs(2028,61): error CS1525: Termo de expressão inválido ')' [D:\CRIS\Programas_Cris\Projeto\Projeto\Projeto.csproj]
  FrmPrincipal.cs(2028,62): error CS1002: ; esperado [D:\CRIS\Programas_Cris\Projeto\Projeto\Projeto.csproj]
  FrmPrincipal.cs(2028,62): error CS1525: Termo de expressão inválido ')' [D:\CRIS\Programas_Cris\Projeto\Projeto\Projeto.csproj]
  FrmPrincipal.cs(2028,63): error CS1002: ; esperado [D:\CRIS\Programas_Cris\Projeto\Projeto\Projeto.csproj]
  FrmPrincipal.cs(2032,13): error CS1525: Termo de expressão inválido 'else' [D:\CRIS\Programas_Cris\Projeto\Projeto\Projeto.csproj]
  FrmPrincipal.cs(2032,17): error CS1002: ; esperado [D:\CRIS\Programas_Cris\Projeto\Projeto\Projeto.csproj]
```

Aqui o arquivo .CsProj

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{2E1B2020-4F0A-4F82-90E0-A08B8D3E0E2F}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Projeto</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Projeto</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationIcon>Icone.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="DotNetZip, Version=1.13.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6583c7c814667745, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\DotNetZip.1.13.8\lib\net40\DotNetZip.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceProcess" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Deployment" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Classes\Funcoes.cs" />
    <Compile Include="FrmImagemPDV.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="FrmImagemPDV.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>FrmImagemPDV.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="FrmPrincipal.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="FrmPrincipal.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>FrmPrincipal.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Classes\INIFile.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="FrmImagemPDV.resx">
      <DependentUpon>FrmImagemPDV.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="FrmPrincipal.resx">
      <DependentUpon>FrmPrincipal.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <None Include="app.config" />
    <None Include="packages.config" />
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Icone.ico" />
    <None Include="Img\Lupa.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Então, sobre o msbuild, você pode comparar os parâmetros que você executa o build com o Visual Studio.
Exemplo:

```
/t:TestTarget
/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0
/p:Configuration=Release
/p:Platform="Any CPU"
/p:DeployOnBuild=True
/p:DeployTarget=Test
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://myserver:8172/MsDeploy.axd
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
```

- Pode ser também a ordem que os projetos (.csproj), são compilados no
  Visual Studio. Esta ordem importa quando se compila no msbuild, pois,
  se não tiver o binário dependente, ele quebra o build.
- Verifique também, se houver, as depenências de pacote nuget.
- Outra coisa a se fazer, é deletar a pasta dos fontes a serem
  compilados e criá-los novamente.

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela resposta, coloquei o arquivo .csproj na pergunta, não sei se esta errado.

Comment: Você precisa comparar os parâmetros de compilação do VIsual Studio com o MSBuild.

Comment: Entendi, aonde encontro esse arquivo do MSBuild ? se puder me dar um exemplo

Comment: o MSBuild é um comando do .net framework usado para compilação.  Para que a compilação seja efetuada com sucesso, você passa alguns parâmetros através de comandos ou um arquivo. Recomendo a leitura: [link]( https://joaoretamero.com.br/compilando-com-msbuild/)